# how do i upload a file to relativepath in spring boot below one is my implementation code

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

```java
@Autowired
private Environment env;

public String UploadFileToAbsolutePath(MultipartFile file ,MultipartFile qrfile,String name,String type)  {
    String directory = env.getProperty("upload.directory");
        String filepath=directory+name;
        String qrfilpath=directory+"qr"+name;
        
        SubComponent filedata=fileDataRepository.save(SubComponent.builder()
                    .name(name)
                    .type(type)
                    .filepath(filepath)
                        .qrfilepath(qrfilpath).build()
                );
    try {
        file.transferTo(new File(filepath));
    } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(file !=null) {
        return "uploadded success "+ filepath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

In `application.properties` I gave `upload.directory=uploads/`  (its showing `upload.directory` is unknown property)

I need to store the multipart file to relative path in spring boot project and give its path to the database

Comment: What is the  location of your `application.properties` file?

Comment: src/main/resources

Comment: This should work... Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: i'm getting IOException after executing the query , thye is being stored in table